# Play h.265 file android

Tags: android-mediaplayer, vlc, exoplayer

Hi is there any way to load h265 file. I am having the below sample file and I want to load it into my player view. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NJHbSVgMS4veLqtVLLNLOfXg6MOgvL9O/view?usp=sharing I tried Exo player but the h265 file format is not supported. Any suggestions for the same?

Comment: https://www.droidviews.com/enjoy-hevc-h-265-video-playback-on-android/

Comment: Thanks @RolfofSaxony but I want to implement it into my project and I am unable to fetch any code for the same I want some code or direction to implement this.